# What is the purpose of loading a value into a register before putting a right-shifted value into it?

Tags: assembly, mips, reverse-engineering, mips32

I'm decompiling a PS2 game that was originally coded in C. To do this, I'm reading MIPS assembler and writing the corresponding C statements.

There's one reoccurring pattern that I haven't been able to figure out. Consider the following assembly:

```
li     v1,2
sra    v1,s1,1
bgez   s1,*+16
nop    
addiu  v1,s1,1
sra    v1,v1,1
daddu  s1,v1,$0
```

The immediate value 2 is loaded into register v1, and is immediately overwritten by the one-bit-right-shifted value of register s1. Next, it checks if s1 was a positive number, and if it wasn't it loads s1 plus one into v1, and shifts it one bit to the right like before. In both cases, the result is then copied back to s1.

The same pattern has also appeared when shifting more bits to the right. Here, it shifts 8 bits to the right, and the immediate values are changed to match:

```
li     v1,256
sra    v1,s1,8
bgez   s1,*+16
nop    
addiu  v1,s1,255
sra    v1,v1,8
daddu  s1,v1,$0
```

After some thinking, this reminded me of two's complement, so I thought it was a result of using the C standard library function abs() to get the absolute value. It made sense, because I always encountered this snippet before the value would be used as an array index, which can't be negative.

Now, I'm not so sure, because since then I've seen it used in situations where negative numbers are allowed and accounted for.

Does anyone have any idea of what this code is for?

Comment: The `li` isn't in the branch delay slot of an earlier branch is it?  After the `li`, the code looks like it's doing signed division by 256, rounding toward 0 like C `x /= 256` instead of rounding toward -Inf like `x >>= 8`.  Or same for `x /= 2;` in your first code block.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's not in a branch delay.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have any use.  I wonder if it was for debugging or something, to find blocks in disassembly or in the debugger.  Or perhaps some hand-written asm, or a clunky compiler that got its peephole optimization wrong and left in a useless instruction?  In both cases the value loaded into `v1` is the divisor, and it's doing `v1 = s1 / v1`, but not actually using the value from `v1`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Given that this game came with debug symbols, it's likely that it's for debugging purposes. If you write all of this up as an answer, I'll accept it. :)

Comment: @old_timer What do you mean by pseudo instruction? As for what I'm looking at, it's the assembly generated from the ELF files by the same linker that originally compiled the C code.

Comment: @old_timer As the linker is closely related to the compiler, I'd guess that counts as generated from a compiler.

Comment: @old_timer I've already told you where I got these snippets of assembly from. ELF files were run through the linker of the compiler that they were originally compiled with. I don't know what else you want me to tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `li` isn't in the branch delay slot of an earlier branch, it's useless.  You're right that its result is overwritten and thus has no effect.

After the `li`, the code looks like it's doing signed division by `2` or `256`, rounding toward 0 like C `x /= 256` instead of rounding toward `-Inf` like `x >>= 8`.

I wonder if it was for debugging or something, to find blocks in disassembly or in the debugger?  Since you say the game came with debug symbols, it could perhaps be intentional for that reason.

In both cases the value loaded into `v1` is the divisor, and it's doing `v1 = s1 / v1`, but not actually using the value from v1.

Or perhaps some hand-written asm, or a clunky compiler that got its peephole optimization wrong and left in a useless instruction?

Comment: li is not an instruction (for an optimizer to leave in).